# Get list of Minters and Amount for Candy Machine

Tags: candy-machine-v2, candy-machine-v3, candymachine

I am looking for an efficient way of getting all the minters and how many they minted from a Candy Machine mint. I'm not 100% on what version was used. Transaction is Candy Machine Core and the inner instruction is MintV2.